# How to display validation error in same page using trigger on click of delete button?

Tags: apex, trigger

How to display validation error in same page without redirecting to new page using trigger on click of delete button?

Answer (score 1):

With a trigger involved, the `addError()` method of the [SObject class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) is what you're looking for.

You'll want to call that on the SObject instance(s) contained in the trigger context variables.

Answer (score 0):

It would also be best if you're going to include a `System.DmlException e` to catch all of the error the you encounter(including validation rule)

Then you can include the following to output the error that you got

```
String S1 = e.getMessage();
            S1 = S1.substringBetween('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, ' , ': [');
           ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,S1 ));
```

Hope this helps